# What needs to be done in Install shield Project to make it capable to uninstall Word Add-In if it is already installed

Tags: vsto, word-addins, installshield-2012

I have two projects as mentioned below.

- VSTO Project(Word Add-In)
- Installer (.ism) project to create installer for above word add-in

Recently, I have made some changes in above both the projects to replace old brand name with new brand name.
After these changes, installer does not uninstall already installed add-in and instead it installs second instance of add-in(having different product name). Earlier, it was able to uninstall existing word add-in.
Please note that I have not changed Product Code and Upgrade Code in ism file.

Now, I want to make installer (created using Install Shield project) capable enough to uninstall existing word add-in (having old product name) if it exists.

The word Add-In is being used by our many clients and after re-branding we want them to re install Add-in. We don't want them to manually uninstall existing word add-in. So, we want to make changes in installer so that it auto detects existing add-in and uninstall it and then install new one.

I am new to the install shield and don't know what is the best and simple way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the latest iterations of InstallShield, but at a minimum you can call vstoinstaller.exe to remove it at the start. It's usually in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTO\10.0`.